# Subscribe is not working while publishing from Python

Tags: python, node.js, zeromq, publish-subscribe

> Original question is here: https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/issues/444

Hi,

If I subscribe from Node.js to a publisher in Python, subscriber can not receive messages. On the other hand, Node-publisher can send both python-subscriber and node-subscriber, python-publisher can send python subscriber.

Node subscriber:

```
// Generated by LiveScript 1.4.0
(function(){
  var zmq, sock;
  zmq = require('zmq');
  sock = zmq.socket('sub');
  sock.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:3000');
  sock.subscribe('');
  console.log('Subscriber connected to port 3000');
  sock.on('message', function(message){
    return console.log('Received a message related to: ', 'containing message: ', message.toString());
  });
}).call(this);
```

Node publisher:

```
// Generated by LiveScript 1.4.0
(function(){
  var zmq, sock;
  zmq = require('zmq');
  sock = zmq.socket('pub');
  sock.bindSync('tcp://127.0.0.1:3000');
  console.log('Publisher bound to port 3000');
  setInterval(function(){
    console.log('Sending a multipart message envelope');
    return sock.send('TestMessage(node)!');
  }, 1500);
}).call(this);
```

Python publisher

```
import zmq
import time

context = zmq.Context()
publisher = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
publisher.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:3000")

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    publisher.send("TestMessage")
    print "Sent"
```

Python subscriber:

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)

socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3000")

while True:
    string = socket.recv()
    print string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the mismatch of libzmq version between `PyZMQ` and `zeromq.node`:

```
$ python 
>>> import zmq
>>> zmq.zmq_version()
'4.0.5'
```

and node version:

```
$ node
> require('zmq').version
'2.2.0'
```

Solution is:

1. Uninstall current version of libzmq: `sudo apt-get purge libzmq-dev`
2. Uninstall current zeromq.node: `sudo npm uninstall zmq -g`
3. Install libzmq-4.x: `sudo apt-get install libzmq3-dev`

   > if this step fails, you need to install libzmq-4.x from source: https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq
4. Install zeromq.node: `sudo npm install zmq`

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the subscriber `sock.on()` call, using a function that has only one parameter (i.e. `data`):

```
(function(){
  var zmq, sock;
  zmq = require('zmq');
  sock = zmq.socket('sub');
  sock.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:3000');
  sock.subscribe('');
  console.log('Subscriber connected to port 3000');
  sock.on('message', function(data){
    return console.log('New message: ', data.toString());
  });
}).call(this);
```

The publisher code should work without any modification, although I prefer something like (Python 3 compatible):

```
import time                                                                     

context = zmq.Context()                                                         
publisher = context.socket(zmq.PUB)                                             
publisher.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:3000")                                          

while True:                                                                     
    time.sleep(1)                                                               
    publisher.send(bytearray('test', 'ascii'))                                  
    print('Sent test message')
```

Comment: Hold on! This code is not working on my laptop, but works on RaspberryPi! Let me debug further...

Comment: This was a libzmq version issue. But there was an error with the code you mentioned, it's also fixed now. Thank you.